# Why does nginx select a location block with a non-matching regex?

Tags: nginx, regex

In my nginx config file I have this `location` block (modified for debugging purposes):

```
location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
    expires 1;
    log_not_found off;
    return 515 "Request URI is $request_uri. Caught you";
}
```

When I request this URI from the server:
`/img/signup/be0e1d34fabf2514d49db9baec09f858.png?w=198&h=198&s=9a7d22504c5ae176a936a0f18cccacba`

sure enough, it matches and I get a 515 response with this body:
`Request URI is /img/signup/be0e1d34fabf2514d49db9baec09f858.png?w=198&h=198&s=9a7d22504c5ae176a936a0f18cccacba. Caught you`

Why? The regex doesn't match, at least not intuitively (either it must end in a question mark followed by a series of digits, or in `.png` etc.), nor when I sense-checked it at [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/HtJaTM/1).

Comment: nginx considers the URI in the location directive to be only the part before the question mark

Comment: Got it, thanks @FedericoSierra. Based on the [documentation for the `location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) referring to the 'request URI' as the string to be compared against, I guessed it was equivalent to the `$request_uri` variable :-( Feel free to add this as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx isn't actually matching against the section after the question mark. Those are the query args. Nginx is only seeing up until the end of the path (`.png`). Since that's the case, it matches just fine.